# Route Blog id with view of Blog in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to click on a blog link and open the blog showing the page of that specific blog. My route config accepts optional id parameters. I am doing this with AJAX as well so hoping to click on a blog link and return to BlogController. I have searched around but cannot find something that helps me..

Here is my code

```
CSHTML

@foreach (var blodID in blogCont)
{
    <a href="??" id="blogHREF" blog-id="@blodID.blogID">
        Text
    </a>
}

AJAX

$(document).on("click", "#blogHREF", function () {
    var retBlogID = $(this).attr("blog-id");

    var blogData = {
        blogID: retBlogID
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Blog/getBlog",
        data: blogData
    });
});


C#   

public class BlogController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult getBlog(blogTable blogged)
    {
        return View(blogged.blogAuthor);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just some things to note about the above. Your `getBlog` method is meant to take a `blogTable` object, it looks like you are passing it something called `blogData` with a `var` type so god knows what that is. Also from this, there is no way you can get `blogged.blogAuthor` as you are simply setting the `ID` in the object. Instead of a `GET` I personally would just `POST`. Also, I don't believe you need the protocol above the method in this case. Also, your `ajax` does not seem correct.

Comment: blogData is just a variable that just holds all the data being sent to the controller. Okay as incorrect, can you please elaborate on what is incorrect?

Comment: I believe you should take a look at this tutorial, in my opinion it's going to be helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-controller

Comment: If you're simply navigating to another page, I, to be honest, would just use a Html helper and pass the variable value you want into the controller

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply navigating to a new page (such as your question suggests) I would simply use a html helper.

```
@Html.Action("getBlog", "Blog", new {blogged = blodID })
```

So this:

```
<a href="??" id="blogHREF" blog-id="@blodID.blogID">
    Text
</a>
```

would be this:

```
<a href="@Html.Action("getBlog", "Blog", new {blogged = blodID })" id="// THIS HAS TO BE UNIQUE">
    Text
</a>
```

This is assuming that `blodID` is a `blogTable`.

Remove the `[HttpGet]`, we don't need it.

Also worth noting that the `id` on your `<a>` tag doesn't look to me to be a unique value. These have to be unique. No matter where you use `Id`'s in HTML.